# is it possible to read values from a tfvars file in Jenkins?

Tags: jenkins, terraform, jenkins-pipeline, nexus

I have some terraform code that uses a map of tfvars to deploy multiple lambdas to Aws. it all works fine except I want to run the script in a Jenkins pipeline which would need to download the jars from Nexus first for each lamda.  is there a way I can read the tfvars file in the Jenkins pipeline to get the names of the jars to download from Nexus, copy them into the working dir on Jenkins and then upload them using terraform?

Comment: First thing that comes to my mind is you could use the `TF_VAR_*` syntax instead of providing values with a tfvars file. That way you could use the env vars in a Jenkins pipeline.